# rspec model spec; testing if local var is assigned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, model, rspec-rails

I'd like to test in my model spec if the local var is set in the method. I tried to use assigns, but it doesn't work in model specs. What is the rails way to do this properly?

user.rb

```
def decreased_chat_number_pusher
  number = self.new_chat_notification #I wanna test if this is set
  Pusher.trigger_async('private-'+ self.id.to_s, 'new_chat_notification', { number: number })
end
```

user_spec.rb

```
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  it "decreased_chat_number_pusher" do
    user.new_chat_notification = 3
    number = user.new_chat_notification
    #FOLLOWING LINE THROWS UNDEFINED METHOD: ASSIGNS
    expect(assigns(number)).to match(user.new_chat_notification)
    allow(Pusher).to receive(:trigger_async).with(('private-' + user.id.to_s), 'new_chat_notification', {number: number} )
    expect(Pusher).to receive(:trigger_async).with(('private-' + user.id.to_s), 'new_chat_notification', {number: number} )
    user.decreased_chat_number_pusher
  end
```

Comment: You can't test locals.  The test takes place outside of (calls and receives) the model method, and locals aren't available outside of a method.  your other allow and expect's should work (are you using fake-pusher?)

Comment: I don't really understand why that matters. There could be one more expect before testing the Pusher part. So I just wanna test separately if number is set. Or did I misunderstand something? As for second part. The Pusher test works fine without the fake-pusher.

Answer (score 1):

> expect(assigns(number)).to match(user.new_chat_notification)

`assigns` does not work in a model spec, as you discovered. AFAIK it is only available in view specs, and even there it tests the value of instance variables, not local variables

A local variable is not a good subject for an assertion, even if you could test it with RSpec. It is part of the implementation of the method -- tests should focus on the *behavior* of the method.

You could change the method signature so `number` can be defined in the test:

```
def decreased_chat_number_pusher(number=new_chat_notification)
```

then you can test the behavior for different values of `number`:

```
expect(decreased_chat_number_pusher).to # succeeds when default value is set
expect(decreased_chat_number_pusher(nil)).to # fails when argument is nil
expect(decreased_chat_number_pusher(:whatever)).to # or pass in any value
```

Comment: Nice solution Zetetic! As I see in this case it's simple and clean to do this. But what is assignment is more complex? Do you have some example in mind when it matters to unit test if some variable is set?

Comment: @SzilardMagyar no, I would argue that you should not write a test that needs to know about the value of local variables. The test should view its subject as a "black box", as far as possible. It is really the same principle as being the consumer (or user) of a method; if you need to know about its internal state, that suggests the method needs refactoring.